# How do I make a clone of a git svn repo also svn-ready?

Tags: git, svn, github

Recently I created a git-svn clone of ICU using:

```
git svn clone -r 38167:HEAD http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk icu
```

It works great. I pushed the repo up to Github and pulled back down as a submodule into another project. However, I noticed that the clone from Github does not have any svn information. How do I set it up so that I can get updated information from svn? I am using Git Extensions where I can SVN Fetch and SVN Rebase the original

The error is that "the current directory is not a valid git-svn repository".

**Update.** Turns out that after pulling down the git repo, it is possible to set up the svn using

```
git svn init http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk
git svn fetch
```

However, this will pull in the entire repository - which for ICU is massive. As an alternative test svn, I am now using

```
git svn clone -r HEAD svn://snowball.tartarus.org/snowball/trunk snowball
```

It does not look like there is a -r flag on git svn init

**Update 2.** The answer for a regular git repository is

```
git svn init http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk
git svn fetch -r HEAD
```

though for a submodule it is still not working and I get errors.

Comment: Would i run git svn init?